# react - calculate total from state data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to this library and just trying to complete some proof of concept functions. I have a `state` with hard coded data that looks like this:

```js
state = { 
    counters: [
        {id: 1, value: 4},
        {id: 2, value: 0},
        {id: 3, value: 1},
        {id: 4, value: 0},
     ],
}
```

I want to create a function to calculate the total of all values in the state, which would be 5 (4+1). I tried this:

```js
getTotal = () => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    let total = 0;
    counters.forEach(function(c) {
        total += c.value;
    });
    return total;
}
```

and added this to my render call:

```js
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar totalCounters= {this.getTotal}/>
         </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

However, in the view, the area is empty. The configuration seems right; if I remove the curly braces content and just put simple text "insert total here", it displays. This leads me to believe my method of calling the function is at fault.

NavBar component is also very simple:

```js
const NavBar = ({totalCounters}) => {
    return ( 
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Total 
                <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">
                    {totalCounters}
                </span>
            </a>
        </nav>
     );
}
     
export default NavBar;
```

### Question

How can I compute the total of the state values and then display the value in my simple rendered view?

Comment: Try changing the function call to: `<NavBar totalCounters= {this.getTotal()}/>`

Comment: You have to invoke the function `{this.getTotal()}`

Comment: You are both correct, thank you. The problem is fixed. Anybody have a tip on  when to call a function and knowing which functions don't need a call?

Comment: Need to invoke the function by adding `()`, voting to close as typo.

Comment: @ArashHowaida as a rule of thumb if you need the value that a function returns you should call it with `()`. But let's say you have a `onClicked` property well then you are not interesting in the value, you are interested in calling a function when you click. So in that case you should just pass the function without calling it. Because the `onClick` will call the function you have provided itself.

Comment: In your fn `getTotal = () => {
  const counters = [...this.state.counters];
  let total = 0;
  counters.forEach(function(c) {
    total += c.value;
  } );
  return total;
}` you could for example extract the add-function to `const addToTotal = function(c) {
    total += c.value;
  } ` and pass that into forEach like this: `getTotal = () => {
  const counters = [...this.state.counters];
  let total = 0;
  counters.forEach(addToTotal);
  return total;
}` and it would still work even though you are not calling the function because forEach will call it for every item in `counters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the link to the function and don't invoke it in the children component. So you should change `render` function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavBar totalCounters={this.getTotal()} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```